# java How to increase the number in elegant way

Tags: java, spring

I have a string type column which includes name of Region.

People can create regions at will.
For example, you can create an area called "Paris". But if the table already has "Paris", I entrusted spring to automatically save as "Paris2".

But the problem is that spring `always save it as "Paris2"`. I think it just check only **does Paris exists**. Can you recommend what to do if you want to be saved as Paris3, Paris4 in elegant way?

```
    String toBeRegionCode = stringReplace(((String)paramBean.get("regionName")).trim());

    if (expediaRegionUnionRepository.findByRegionCodeCount(toBeRegionCode) == 0) {
            insert.setRegionCode(toBeRegionCode);
    } else {
           insert.setRegionCode(toBeRegionCode + "" + (expediaRegionUnionRepository.findByRegionCodeCount(toBeRegionCode) + 1));
    }
```

This is the code that always makes Paris2. How to improve Paris3 Paris4 return?

Comment: You should put your integer value in a separate column for easy tracking of duplicate names.

Comment: @jnrdn0011 ok. thanks for the answer. Then it would be better to just append the uuid to the string.

Comment: Yes, and you need to modify your repository method to get the top 1 matching data in desc order by the count. In this way you will get the last incremented value.